# Use loading circle of newest Android version for all versions

Tags: android, animation, loading, android-styles

I have an app and that app has a loading circle. The loading circle looks nice in Android 4.2 and above. But below it doesn't look the same. Is there a way to have the loading circle of the newest Android version for every version? Currently I'm doing it with a style in the styles.xml. But this doesn't look the way I want it. I just want, that it looks everywhere the same. Any idea how to do that?

This is the current Style

```
<style name="GenericProgressBackground" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>    
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#DD111111</item>    
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>  
</style>
<style name="GenericProgressIndicator" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item> 
</style>
```

And the progressbar in my layout uses the style of course

`style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator"`

Comment: You may need to copy the drawables as well. Is this the correct styles for the new progress drawable?

Comment: Yes, the progress bar has `style="@style/GenericProgressIndicator"` and it works correctly. I don't worry about that. I worry about that it is ugly. :p I want it to look like the newest ones from android 4.2 and above.

Comment: follow the this link https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel it is very good to design loading circle